# What happens when you are unable to move in Stratego?

Tags: stratego

What happens if you are a in a situation in which you are unable to make a valid move in Stratego?
For example what would happen in the following situations:

- Your only pieces remaining are the stationary bombs and flag pieces
- You have non-stationary pieces, but they are trapped behind your bombs/flags and therefore unable to move

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Straight from [page 5 of the rules](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/Stratego.pdf):

> Note: if a player cannot move a piece or strike in his/her turn, they must give up and declare their opponent the winner.

So, yeah, don't set up your bombs and flags in a manner that prevents most of your troops from being movable without the bombs being removed by an opposing miner (that's actually another easily-missed point - the only way for a bomb to leave the board is if a miner hits it. Any other piece is simply lost while the bomb stays). You will be forced to forfeit if you cannot make any move at all.

Comment: Ah thanks, couldn't find it when googling specifically for "can't move in stratego". One additional related question, would you still lose if your only valid move was against rule 10 "pieces cannot be moved back and forth between the same 2 squares in 3 consecutive turns"?

Comment: I don't see why rule 10 would be superceded by another rule...

Comment: Note that if *both players* are unable to move (e.g. if the last two equal pieces are exchanged), the game is a draw, regardless of who is to move. See the official rules of the [International Stratego Federation](http://isfstratego.kleier.net/docs/rulreg/isfgamerules.pdf) (rule 12.3)